# Get the order id on WooCommerce "Order received" Thankyou page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, endpoint, orders

I will customize the thankyou page from my WoocCommerce shop.
For this I added a blanc thankyou.php into the WooCommerce checkout directory.

I tried this code

```
function get_order($order_id) {
    echo $order_id;
}
add_action('woocommerce_thankyou', 'get_order');
```

But the variable $order_id is empty.

Is there somebody who knows how I get the order id on the thankyou page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If Url is like `www.example.com/checkout/order-received/1234/?key=wc_order_s5ou6md6nTZDds` you can use the following to get the order id:

```
global $wp;

if ( isset($wp->query_vars['order-received']) ) {
    $order_id = absint($wp->query_vars['order-received']); // The order ID
    $order    = wc_get_order( $order_id ); // The WC_Order object
}
```